# Enable backspace to go to the previous page in Firefox

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

I want to enable or use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to switch back to previous page that I visited previously in the Firefox browser on Ubuntu. For example, if I am using any browser on Windows, I can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> instead of back button in browser to go to previously visited page.

Comment: Which browser are you talking about? By the way, this is a browser issue, not an OS issue.

Comment: @edwinksl, I am using Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Wow, somebody actually requesting to revive this awful bug. https://xkcd.com/1172/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not an OS issue, but this way you will get it to work

Open your Mozilla Firefox browser, and in the address bar, type `about:config`. Then search for `browser:backspace_action`. Since the entries are in alphabetical order, it's essy to look for it. When you have found it, `double click` on it and change its value to **0** from **2**. That's it.

You will find these steps in detail in the following article (see link)

https://itsfoss.com/enable-backspace-firefox-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: I don't know if there have been changes in Firefox, but nowadays the setting is _browser.backspace_action_. Then, I had to change the value to 0, not 2.

Comment: I confirm that changing the setting from 2 to 0 was also the way for me (Ubuntu 20.04, Firefox 84.0)

Answer (score 43):

Type `about:config` in the address bar of Firefox and search for `browser.backspace_action`. Change its value from `2` to `0` and now you can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to go back in history.

Comment: This worked for me.